# Calling method from State class

Tags: flutter

Given a stateful widget, is somehow possible to call a method defined in the State class (the one which `extends State<NameOfTheWidget>`). Actually, I just want to rebuild the _State class, like calling setState() but from outside of the class. I know how to it from children to parents but not viceversa.

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget{
  State createState() => new _State();
  //...bar() ??
}

class _State extends State<Foo>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}

  void bar(){...}
}
```

**EDIT**: some real code

First, we hace the equivalent to the inner widget; it's a a customized text field. The point is that I want enable and disable it according to the boolean _activo variable.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bukit/widgets/ensure.dart';

class EntradaDatos extends StatelessWidget{
  final String _titulo;
  final String _hint;
  TextEditingController _tec;
  FocusNode _fn = new FocusNode();
  final String Function(String s) _validador;
  final TextInputType _tit;
  bool _activo;

  /*
   *  CONSTRUCTOR
   */
  EntradaDatos(this._titulo, this._hint, this._validador, this._tit, this._activo){
    _tec = new TextEditingController();     
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    print('Construyendo');
    return new EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
      focusNode: _fn,
      child: new TextFormField(
        enabled: _activo,
        keyboardType: _tit,
        validator: _validador,
        autovalidate: true,
        focusNode: _fn,
        controller: _tec,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: _titulo,
          hintText: _hint
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  String getContenido(){
    return _tec.text;
  }
}
```

Then I have a concrete implementation of the previous text field, which just extends it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bukit/widgets/entrada_datos.dart';

class EntradaMail extends EntradaDatos{

  static String _hint = "nombre@dominio.es";
  static String _validador(String s){
    if(s.isEmpty){
      return 'El campo es obligatorio';
    }else{
      if(!s.contains('@') || !s.contains('.') || s.contains(' ')){
        return 'Introduce una dirección válida';
      }else{
        String nombre = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('@'));
        String servidor = s.substring(s.indexOf('@')+1, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
        String dominio = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        if(nombre.length < 2 || servidor.length < 2 || dominio.length < 2){
          return 'Introduce una dirección válida';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  EntradaMail(String titulo, bool activo) : super(titulo, _hint, _validador, TextInputType.emailAddress, activo);
}
```

Finally, the equivalent of my outter widget. It's just a checkbox followed by the prevoius `EntradaEmail` widget. As far as I know, once the checkbox is pressed and the onChange call is made, the setState call should rebuild everything, but I've contrasted with debug messaged that the build method of the first inner widget is never called. My point is enabling and disabling the text field according to the checkbox.

```
class CampoEnvio extends StatefulWidget{

  EntradaMail _mail;
  EntradaMovil _movil;
  String _tituloMail;
  String _tituloMovil;  
  bool _usaMail = false;
  bool _usaMovil = false;

  CampoEnvio(this._tituloMail, this._tituloMovil){
    _mail = new EntradaMail(_tituloMail, _usaMail);
    _movil = new EntradaMovil(_tituloMovil, _usaMovil);
  }

  State createState() => _State(_mail, _movil, _usaMail, _usaMovil, _tituloMail, _tituloMovil);

}

class _State extends State<CampoEnvio>{

  bool _usaMail;
  bool _usaMovil;
  String _tituloMail;
  String _tituloMovil;
  EntradaMail _mail;
  EntradaMovil _movil;

  _State(this._mail, this._movil, this._usaMail, this._usaMovil, this._tituloMail, this._tituloMovil);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          leading: new SizedBox(
            width: 70.0,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Checkbox(
                  value: _usaMail,
                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _usaMail = value;                 
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          title: _mail,
        ),
        //...
        new Divider()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please little elaborate? Maybe you can tell why/when you want to call `bar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that you added the sample code, I will try to explain why your widget does not work, and I will try to explain what other improvements can be made.

---

First of all, you can improve the readability of your code by using named constructors for all of your widgets, like in my other answers (You can auto-generate them with Android Studio: Define some final fields, then press the lightbulb button to generate the constructor).

---

The next problem is that widgets which create a `TextEditingController` must always be stateful widgets! Otherwise the input made by the user will disappear after every build!

Usually you would pass in the `TextEditingController` from a parent widget (the widget that handles processes data when you submit it)

---

Also, it is discouraged to extend widgets. Instead, use composition, e.g.:

```
class EntradaMail extends StatelessWidget {
  final String titulo;
  // ...    
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return EntradaDatos(
      titulo: titulo,
      //...
    )
  }
}
```

---

Widget properties should always be public and final (never start with a `_`).

---

You are doing some strange things in `CampoEnvio`.

First of all, you are for some reason passing in all the properties of the widget to the `State` in `createState`. That has some consequences which you probably don't intend.

In general it is **extremely** rare that your `State` class has constructor parameters, and usually you would **not** pass properties from the stateful widget to the state.

The problem is that `createState` is only called once, it is not called again when you call `initState` in a parent widget. The state is kept until the widget is disposed.

That means your state constructor is only called once as well, and the fields in `_State` (of `CampoEnvio`) will stay the same all the time. Even when the parent is rebuilt and calls the constructor of `CampoEnvio` again, the old values in `_State` will not be replaced.

---

It's also very stange that you are creating widgets (`EntradaMail` and `EntradaMovil`) in the `StatefulWidget`.

The class that extends `StatefulWidget` should not do that! It is basically just a "bag" of properties.

---

Here is the complete fixed sample code, following the conventions explained above:

```
class EntradaDatos extends StatefulWidget {
  EntradaDatos({Key key, this.titulo, this.hint, this.validador, this.tit, this.activo}) : super(key: key);

  final String titulo;
  final String hint;

  final String Function(String s) validador;
  final TextInputType tit;
  final bool activo;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _EntradaDatosState();
}

class _EntradaDatosState extends State<EntradaDatos> {
  // FocusNode and TextEditingController must be the same for the whole lifetime of the widget
  // => put into State
  TextEditingController _tec;
  FocusNode _fn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tec = new TextEditingController();
    _fn = new FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Construyendo');
    return new EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
        focusNode: _fn,
        child: new TextFormField(
          enabled: widget.activo,
          keyboardType: widget.tit,
          validator: widget.validador,
          autovalidate: true,
          focusNode: _fn,
          controller: _tec,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: widget.titulo, hintText: widget.hint),
        ));
  }

  String getContenido() {
    return _tec.text;
  }
}

class EntradaMail extends StatelessWidget {
  static String _hint = "nombre@dominio.es";

  static String _validador(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty) {
      return 'El campo es obligatorio';
    } else {
      if (!s.contains('@') || !s.contains('.') || s.contains(' ')) {
        return 'Introduce una dirección válida';
      } else {
        String nombre = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('@'));
        String servidor = s.substring(s.indexOf('@') + 1, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
        String dominio = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if (nombre.length < 2 || servidor.length < 2 || dominio.length < 2) {
          return 'Introduce una dirección válida';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  EntradaMail({Key key, this.titulo, this.activo}) : super(key: key);

  final String titulo;
  final bool activo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use composition instead of inheritance
    return EntradaDatos(
      titulo: titulo,
      activo: activo,
      validador: _validador,
      hint: _hint,
      tit: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    );
  }
}

class CampoEnvio extends StatefulWidget {
  const CampoEnvio({Key key, this.tituloMail, this.tituloMovil}) : super(key: key);

  final String tituloMail;
  final String tituloMovil;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _CampoEnvioState();
}

class _CampoEnvioState extends State<CampoEnvio> {
  // I guess these variables are modified here using setState
  bool _usaMail;
  bool _usaMovil;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // just rebuild the widgets whenever build is called!
    final mail = new EntradaMail(
      titulo: widget.tituloMail,
      activo: _usaMail,
    );
    final movil = new EntradaMovil(
      titulo: widget.tituloMovil,
      activo: _usaMovil,
    );

    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          leading: new SizedBox(
            width: 70.0,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Checkbox(
                  value: _usaMail,
                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _usaMail = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          title: mail,
        ),
        //...
        new Divider()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It always helps to look at the official samples in the Flutter repositories!

Comment: Thanks you so much for your explanatory answer, just one last quesion: is there any way to acces the TextEditingController from the outter widget, or shall declare it in _CampoEnvioState and pass it as an argument for the constructor (and so on with EntradaMail)? Thanks once again.

Comment: You would declare the `TextEditingController` in the outer widget (must be stateful) and save it there in a variable in the `State` , then pass down the controller using constructor parameters (e.g. final `controller` field in `EntradaDatos` class and `EntradaMail` class.). In the `_EntradaDatosState` class you would then access the controller via `widget.controller`

Comment: All right, I see. Just for educational purpose: which would be the difference between that, and defining the controller in the deepest widget, and then pushing up the content of that controller with a getter-like function?

Comment: First of all you would probably save the same value in 2 places (the controller in the child widget, and some parent widget that also saves the value when your function is called), which is never a good idea.

Comment: And the controller always gives you access to the current value, while the function only reports changes.

Comment: `TextEditingController` is kind of like a hack in Flutter (a good one). It breaks with the traditional pattern of passing down data via constructor parameters, and passing up events (user changed text) via callback functions.

Comment: Same with `AnimationController`, `ScrollController`, `PageController`: Those controllers allow you to manipulate the state of a child, and they also give you access to the current state of the child

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in theory it is possible using a `GlobalKey`, **but not recommended!**

```
class OuterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => OuterWidgetState();
}

class OuterWidgetState extends State<OuterWidget> {
  final _innerKey = GlobalKey<InnerWidgetState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        InnerWidget(key: _innerKey),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('call foo'),
          onPressed: () {
            _innerKey.currentState.foo();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class InnerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  InnerWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => InnerWidgetState();
}

class InnerWidgetState extends State<InnerWidget> {
  String _value = 'not foo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_value);
  }

  void foo() {
    setState(() {
      _value = 'totally foo';
    });
  }
}
```

---

Better approach: Instead, what it would be a good idea to pull the state up:

```
class OuterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => OuterWidgetState();
}

class OuterWidgetState extends State<OuterWidget> {
  String _innerValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        InnerWidget(value: _innerValue),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('call foo'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _innerValue = 'totally foo';
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class InnerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  InnerWidget({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  final String value;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => InnerWidgetState();
}

class InnerWidgetState extends State<InnerWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.value);
  }
}
```

---

If you can, make the inner widget stateless:

```
class InnerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  InnerWidget({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(value);
  }
}
```

---

If your child is interactive (taps, checkbox...), you can define callbacks with `VoidCallback` or `ValueChanged<T>` (or your own `typedef`) to process the events in the parent widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @boformer, your second aproach was eaxctly what I was doing. However, once I call setState() in the outter widget, the inner one doesn't rebuild. The only difference I can see is that I'm not using a key in the constructor of the inner widget.

Comment: That's strange. When you call `setState` on the outer widget, the inner widget should always rebuild. Always, even without a `key` in the constructor. Can you share your exact code? Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: see my second answer